# Mongoose - MissingSchemaError on population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two mongoose models:

1- Event model:

```
eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  location: {
    type: { type: String, default: 'Point', required: true },
    coordinates: { type: [Number], required: true },
  },
  sport: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Sport',
    required: true,
  },
  startDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  host: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  players: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
}, { timestamps: true });
```

2- User model:

```
userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
  },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

In my `EventService` I'm trying to find one event by id and return the `sport` `host` and `players` fields populated. The first two fields don't throw any error when populating and works fine, but the problem is with the `players` field. It throws this error:

```
{ MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "players".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at MissingSchemaError (/Users/elias/Documents/tfg/sporter-app/sporter-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/missingSchema.js:20:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.model (/Users/elias/Documents/tfg/sporter-app/sporter-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:1043:11)
    at getModelsMapForPopulate (/Users/elias/Documents/tfg/sporter-app/sporter-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3569:20)
    at populate (/Users/elias/Documents/tfg/sporter-app/sporter-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3113:15)
    at _populate (/Users/elias/Documents/tfg/sporter-app/sporter-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3081:5)
    at Function.Model.populate (/Users/elias/Documents/tfg/sporter-app/sporter-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3041:5)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/elias/Documents/tfg/sporter-app/sporter-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1441:17)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/elias/Documents/tfg/sporter-app/sporter-api/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:137:16)
    at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)
  message: 'Schema hasn\'t been registered for model "players".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)',
  name: 'MissingSchemaError' }
```

Finally this is how I'm calling the `.populate()` method:

```
const event = await Event.findById(eventId)
  .populate('sport', 'host', 'players')
  .exec();
```

Any idea on what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const event = await Event.findById(eventId)
  .populate('sport')
  .populate('host')
  .populate('players')
  .exec()
```

There is a section **Populating multiple paths** in the docs here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html